# What is the difference between FORECAST.ETS function in Excel and Exponential Smoothing forecast in Data Analyst Tool Pack Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics, forecasting, forecast

In Excel 2016, there is a formula for forecast called FORECAST.ETS,
Whereas, there is also an Excel Adds-In Data Analyst for forecast called Exponential Smoothing.
Is it the same function or different?

Comment: Excel usually has a help file entry for every function - what explanation is given for those you mention?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [FORECAST.ETS(.) documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forecast-ets-function-15389b8b-677e-4fbd-bd95-21d464333f41), the function implements the AAA (additive noise, additive trend, and additive seasonality) version of the ETS.

For the Exponential Smoothing function in the Data Analysis, the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-analysis-toolpak-to-perform-complex-data-analysis-6c67ccf0-f4a9-487c-8dec-bdb5a2cefab) is very brief, so I examined the output formulas in Excel: it is clear that the output implements (Brown's) simple exponential smoothing, so there is no account or treatment for the trend of the seasonality components, just the level.

The FORECAST.ETS can better smooth data with a trend and (or) seasonal patterns.